# two programs accessing one file

Tags: xcode, fopen

New to this forum - looks great!
I have some Processing code that periodically reads data wirelessly from remote devices and writes that data as bytes to a file, e.g. data.dat.  I want to write an Objective C program on my Mac Mini using Xcode to read this file, parse the data, and act on the data if data values indicate a problem.  My question is: can my two different programs access the same file asynchronously without a problem?  If this **is** a problem can you suggest a technique that will allow these operations?
Thanks,
Kevin H.

Comment: please pay a little more attention when using tags. "Processing" is a programming language, and your question had nothing to do with that language.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'll be more careful in the future.  Though I didn't state it explicitly, the Processing code writes to the file and I want to read that file using my C code so, technically, my question did have something to do with Processing, but I didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple processes can read from the same file at a time without any problem. A process can also read from a file while another writes without problem, although you'll have to take care to ensure that you read in any new data that was written. Multiple processes should not *write* to the same file at at the same time, though. The OS will let you do it, but the ordering of data will be undefined, and you'll like overwrite data—in general, you're gonna have a bad time if you do that. So you should take care to ensure that only one process writes to a file at a time.

The simplest way to protect a file so that only one process can write to it at a time is with the C function [`flock()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/flock.2.html), although that function is admittedly a bit rudimentary and may or may not suit your use case.

Comment: This exactly addresses my problem.  Thanks for the useful, concise answer.